# Conda does not work anymore after installing Jupyter Hub

Tags: python, conda

I've installed jupyter-hub on my machine that was running smoothly with jupyter-lab, conda and python3.6.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub
```

Now conda seems to not work anymore giving this error:

```
[pas.datascience_dev@devrmdatasci01 site-packages]$ conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/pyconda3/bin/conda", line 12, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'conda'
```

Now if i run python, it seems to use python3.7 packaged by conda-forge

```
[pas.datascience_dev@devrmdatasci01 python3.6]$ python
Python 3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

If i go to my python installation path i can see both a directory python3.6 and a directory python3.7, the first contain correctly conda and all other packages i was using, the other none

How can i revert, disintall python3.7 or stop using it and recode all to use the old python3.6 that was working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert in this, but you can always uninstall python and reinstall it, although I don't know if it keeps the libraries you've downloaded.

my suggestion is run pip install conda, although I'm not sure how it works on Linux.

Comment: the problem is that the old python3.6 has a lot of packages installed and custom configuration ....

Comment: @RevivedPicard just run pip install conda again. that is how I got conda on my python, it will probably revert it but sill keep everything

Comment: After installing with pip install conda

[pas.datascience_dev@devrmdatasci01 site-packages]$ conda
ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip install conda`
or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using conda as an application.
If your intention is to install conda as a standalone application, currently
supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda
installer.  You can download the miniconda installer from
https://conda.io/miniconda.html.

I cannot use conda to install packages and so on and still see python3.7

Comment: I think it is because you are on Linux, how to get conda on Linux: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html   I really hope it works for you cos I have no idea how Linux works